# Addressing polysemy in NLP tasks

Tags: classification, nlp, topic-model, question-answering

Looking for modern algorithms using NN Language Model implementations addressing polysemy in NLP tasks, including text classification, question answering and topic modeling. Transfer/Zero-short learning methods are most interesting to find. Any working solutions with BERT and Hugging Face Transformers libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article will help you [How Contextual are Contextualized Word Representations? Comparing the Geometry of BERT, ELMo, and GPT-2 Embeddings](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.00512).

Talks about contextual word embeddings like BERT and GPT how they can capture various polysemous concepts rather than the static word embeddings which create a single representation for each word, such as GloVe.